# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ServiceBodyAreas'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ServiceBodyAreas'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have in my database a table of Services and a table of BodyAreas. They are linked by a many to many relation. Here I'm trying to load Services from a CSV in which I have a also the related BodyAreas.

```
var record = reader.GetRecord<ServiceModel>();

service.Name = record.Service;
service.Code = record.ID;
service.Description = record.Description;
service.Price = decimal.Parse(record.Price_Uninsured);
service.Specialties = new[]
    {
    context.Specialties.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == record.Category),
    };
service.ServiceType = serviceType;
service.BodyAreas = new List<BodyArea>();
string[] items = record.Body_Areas.Split(new char[] { ',' });
foreach (var item in items)
{
    BodyArea bA = context.BodyAreas.Single(x => x.Name == item);
    if (bA != null)
    {
        service.BodyAreas.Add(bA);
    }
}

var entry = context.Entry(service);
if (entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(service);
else
    context.Services.Add(service);
```

But when I run the update-database command from the package manager console I get this error:

> InnerException = {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_dbo.ServiceBodyAreas'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.ServiceBodyAreas'. The duplicate key value is (1, 17).\r\nThe
>   statement has been terminated."}

Comment: hope your Body_Areas has no duplicate element

Comment: thanks a lot man. I feel very stupid right now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not trying to fill in duplicate values; try to avoid duplicates in the below line of code; you may use `Distinct` to get unique values;

```
string[] items = record.Body_Areas.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```